# Black Crumb Nuisance

Tags: football

Every Sunday I play five a side football at the local 3G pitches. Every Sunday I bring home hundreds if not thousands of the small black bits used to fill the pitch. This in itself is a nightmare, however recently I've also started developing blisters as a result of these little black bits ending up inside my boots.

I often stop during play now to empty my boots, however this is both time consuming and annoying.

Does anyone else experience this? If so any advice on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those black crumbs used in 3G pitches are rubber pellets. (These often come from used tyres and other scrap materials. [There are unproven claims that these are cancer risks.](http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/football/news/fifa-bosses-urged-investigate-health-7284586) So I'd advise you to ensure none of these enter your body during play.) These pellets are useful as they provide a good grip when running on the artificial pitch, which is made of plastics which can be slippery. However, if the quantity of them that makes it inside your shoe is so high, perhaps you should try and convince the ground staff to scrape off the excess amount.

To address your current problem, I had faced a similar problem earlier and I realized this is attributed to the fit and shape of the football shoes/studs you use. My previous shoes were a decent fit but the design of the shoe (which could be worsened by use) was such that the mouth of the shoe did not close firmly around the ankle. As a result, the open mouth of the shoe allowed pellets to slide into the space and slowly work their way inwards with each stride. When I purchased a new pair which had a closed mouth, the quantity of pellets in my shoe were reduced tenfold. I still find quite a few pellets in my shoes when I take them off after the game, but I hardly need to stop mid-game to get rid of them. Additionally, you should consider wearing a thicker pair of socks as this would reduce the sensitivity of your feet to these foreign objects inside your shoes.

PS: I am unable to provide links or pictures regarding the two contrasting shoe designs, but I hope I have been able to explain the design issue quite clearly.

Comment: http://www.new-football-boots.com/images/1015Boots/Adidas-Leo-Messis-2014-F50-adiZero-TRX-TF-football-boots-serpentine-white_3.jpg

Comment: I have recently (around 3months ago) purchased the above boots. Coincidentally this is also when we changed pitch location so didn't even consider the boot could be the issue. To be totally honest I didn't even realise there were different kinds of opening. Will try my old boots on the new pitch for a while see how that goes.

Comment: It's about how the boots fit your feet. Perhaps you're wearing one size too big. In any case, there is no set rule about the shoe opening. But from personal experience, I found a solution to a similar problem and it lay in changing the boots to a pair that fit more snugly, allowing little place for the pellets to enter the shoe.